# Where can I find the untranslated Greek text of Plato's republic?

Tags: reference-request, plato

I can't find the original text anywhere online.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Perseus Collection](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/collection?collection=Perseus:corpus:perseus,Greek+Texts&redirect=true) is a great online collection of ancient texts in their original languages (with a built in translation dictionary) as well as lots of different English translations. [Here](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3atext%3a1999.01.0167) is the Republic.

There are also multiple scans of the text on archive.org. For example, here is [Part I](https://archive.org/details/republicshorey01platuoft) and [Part II](https://archive.org/details/republicshorey02platuoft) of [Paul Shorey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Shorey)'s 1935 publication, it has the original Greek as well as his English translation side by side.